# Send grid api sends the attachment with different encoding

Tags: asp.net, encoding, outlook, sendgrid

I have an issue where we are using ASP.NET framework and SendGrid api/sdk to send the email to users. We have the attachment name in Spanish character as shown below but when the mail is received it encodes differently in outlook. In Gmail, the Spanish characters are shown correctly, but this issue is with Outlook.

I have tried different ways like normalizing string and converting into base64 but that approach doesn't work. It is only happening with email attachments but not with email body. I came to know SendGrid by default converts for Ascii to UTF-8 encoding. Refer the code below.

[image]

[image]

This issue is more prevalent in outlook, can someone share the solution.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you try to send emails manually? Have you tried to contact SendGrid developers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using UTF32 to encode the file name and send it to SendGrid. I would recommend you try UTF8.

Comment: this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue currently with SendGrid and have found a solution.

If you add:

```
<!-- ™ -->
```

After your charset declaration this will force the html body to be utf-8, you can add any non ASCII character and your filenames will come out correct.

I have attached the example below with your character and other non ASCII characters.

[File name with non ASCII Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Fd5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
var fileName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(file.FileName);
msg.AddAttachment(fileName, base64Data);
```